# Nonlinear second order differential equation involving sine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, nonlinear-system, differential

I need to solve this ODE:

$A +B\frac{dy}{dt}+C\sin(y)+\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = 0$

where A, B, and C are constants, and  $y$  is  $y(t)$.

I manage to reduce the order of the ODE by using dimension analysis to:

$A +B\frac{dy}{dt}+\sin(y) = 0$

where A and B are constant, and $y$ is $y(t)$

I would like to know the analytic solution for the 1st order ode (and if it's a possibility for the 2nd order as well).

I'm working on a numerical solution just in case there is no solution for that problem, in the meanwhile.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Considering$$A +B\,y'+C\sin(y)+y'' = 0$$ start switching variables to make
$$A+\frac B {t'}+C\sin(y)-\frac{t''}{[t']^3}=0$$ which makes the reduction of order quite obvious. So
$$A+\frac B {p}+C\sin(y)-\frac{p'}{p^3}=0$$ If I am not mistaken, we should arrive to something like
$$\frac 1 p=-\frac A B+\frac{C (\cos (y)-B \sin (y))}{B^2+1}+k\, e^{-B y}$$

Doing the same with

$$A +B\,y'+\sin(y) = 0\implies t'=-\frac{B}{A+\sin (y)}$$ which is quite simple using the tangent half-angle subsitution.

Making the story short, we should get
$$t=k-\frac{2 B }{\sqrt{A^2-1}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{A \tan
   \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)+1}{\sqrt{A^2-1}}\right)$$ which can be inversed.

Comment: Thanks Claude! Really interesting solution, can you explain more on "if I'm not mistaken", I'm not as sharp as you on this subject. I lost you there.

Answer (score 0):

$$y''(x)+By'+c \sin y +A=0~~~~(1)$$
Let $y'=p$, then
$$\frac{dp}{dx}+Bp+c \sin y+A=0~~~~(2)$$
$\frac{dp}{dx}=p\frac{dp}{dy}$, then
$$p\frac{dp}{dy}+Bp+C \sin y+A=0$$
$$pdp+(Bp+C \sin y+A)dy=0~~~(3)$$
Multiply (3) by $e^{By}$
$$p~e^{By} dp+e^{By}(Bp+C \sin y+A)dy=0~~~(3)$$
(3) becomes an Exact Eq.
Whose solution is
$$\int pe^{By} dp \text{(treat $y$ as const)}+\int e^{By}(C \sin y+A) dy=G$$
$$\implies e^{By}\frac{p^2}{2}+e^{By}\left( \frac{B^2C \sin y- BC \cos y+A+AB^2}{B+B^3}\right)$$
$$\implies p=\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\sqrt{2}G+\sqrt{2}\frac{Bc\sin y-B^2C \sin y-A-AB^2}{(B+B^3)}}$$
Given the values of A,B,C, this integral can be solved to get $y(x)$ with two constants $G$ and one more $H$.

Comment: That's nice! , but I'm not sure how I get y(x) from here. I need to integrate $\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}G+\sqrt{2}\frac{Bc\sin y-B^2C \sin y-A-AB^2}{(B+B^3)}}}=dx$ and sin(y) is depend on y itself

Answer (score 0):

$$y''+by'+c\sin y+a=0$$
Multiply it by $2y'$ to get
$$2y'y''+2by'^2+2c\sin y y'+2ay'=0$$
$$\implies \frac{dy'^2}{dx}+2by'^2=-(2c\sin y+2a) \frac{dy}{dx}.$$
$$\frac{d (e^{2by}y'^2)}{dx}=-2(c\sin y+2) \frac{dy}{dx} e^{2by}$$
Integrate both sides w.r. $x$, to get
$$y'^2e^{2by}=-2\int e^{2by}(c\sin y+a) dy$$
$$y'^2=-2e^{-2by}\int e^{2by}(c\sin y+a) dy +ge^{-2by}$$
From here one can carry on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ahmed, but I don't understand where the exponent came from, I try to derivate the term (exp(2by*y')) but it's not equal to the previous row. can you explain it step by step?

Comment: Let $y'^2=z$ then $\frac{dz}{dx}+p(x) z =e^{-\int p(x)dx}\frac{d z(e^{\int p(x) dx))}}{dx}$. Also one exponential factor was missing. Please see it again.

Comment: Thanks man, but I still think that : $\frac{d (e^{2by}y'^2)}{dx} = \frac{d (e^{2by})}{dx}y'^2+\frac{d (y'^2)}{dx}e^{2by}=2by'e^{2by}y'^2+\frac{d (y'^2)}{dx}e^{2by}=2be^{2by}y'^3+\frac{d (y'^2)}{dx}e^{2by}$ and that doesn't equal to $(\frac{dy'^2}{dx}+2by'^2)e^{2by}$

Comment: It should be $e^{2bt}$ as integrating factor. Which renders the second half of the calculation unrelated to the given DE.